# AWS SDK load credentials in Goland not working

Tags: go, aws-sdk, goland

I am trying to leverage `credentials.NewEnvCredentials()` alleged ability to pull credential information from `~/.aws/credentials` file but for some reason this code errors out and says it cannot find my AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY. When I add these variables manually to my Goland run config environment variables, I get a successful connection. But for deployment, I need to be able to access the values in the `~/.aws/credentials` file. Does anyone know how to make this work? For Goland specifically?

```
    var DefaultTransport http.RoundTripper = &http.Transport{
        Dial: (&net.Dialer{
            Timeout:   30 * time.Second,
            KeepAlive: 30 * time.Second,
        }).Dial,
        TLSHandshakeTimeout: 10 * time.Second,
    }

    credentialsEnv := credentials.NewEnvCredentials()
    signer := v4.NewSigner(credentialsEnv)

    client := &http.Client{Transport: DefaultTransport}

    signedClient, signerError := aws_signing_client.New(signer, client, "es", "us-east-1")

    if signerError != nil {
        fmt.Errorf("Unable to create aws signed http transport client object: %v", signerError)
    }

    opensearchConfig := opensearch.Config{
        Addresses: parameters.Addresses,
        //Username:  parameters.Username,
        //Password:  parameters.Password,
        //Username: "mercury",
        //Password: "",
        Transport: signedClient.Transport,
        //Transport: tp,
    }

    opensearchClient, err := opensearch.NewClient(opensearchConfig)
    fmt.Println(opensearchClient.Info())
```

I tried manually exporting AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY in the terminal of my Goland IDE but even then, Goland seems to ignore them. It only works if I hard code AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and session token. Of course, this is not the goal. I would prefer to only have to export the AWS profile.

Comment: Is your [AWS_PROFILE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html#cli-configure-files-using-profiles) environment variable set correctly, as `NewEnvCredentials()` pullup the same user from .credentials as in this variable? Check it in shell.